# How to find address is invalid even if Google returns geocoding?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX to get geocoding from google, but some of addresses are actually invalid, Google still returns an alternative geocoding, most likely the center of the city. Is there any way that I could know it is actually an invalid address so I can avoid use these inaccurate geocoding? For example, the following address is inaccurate, so how can I find it is n invalid address even Google map service returns a geocoding?

```
{
declare

l_address varchar2(4000);
l_url varchar2(32000);
l_response varchar2(3200);

BEGIN
    /* TODO implementation required */

    l_address:=APEX_UTIL.URL_ENCODE('Rt. 1 Box 97-5 Braggs Muskogee Oklahoma 74423');
    dbms_output.put_line(l_address);
    l_address := replace(l_address,' ','+');

    l_url := 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='||l_address||'&'||'output=csv';
    l_response := utl_http.request(l_url, APEX_APPLICATION.G_PROXY_SERVER);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_response);
    l_response:=substr(l_response,instr(l_response,',',1,2)+1);

    dbms_output.put_line('In function: l_response ='||l_response);



END;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [geocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) takes an address and returns the associated geographic coordinates.  It is not an [address validator](https://www.google.com/?q=address+validation&output=search&sclient=psy-ab#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=address+validation&oq=address+validation) (although people keep trying to use it as one).

[This post](http://gabesumner.com/address-validation-using-the-google-maps-api) found in the search for address validation above, show how one person is using it.